# How can I resolve Invalid identifier in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle

Got ora-00904: age invalid identifier.ora-06512. I have tried changing the variables didn't work out.
I'm not getting where the issue is. I am new to oracle. Please help me.

```
create or replace procedure select_proc_student(

  name varchar2(20), age number,
  mobile number,
  sresult out SYS_REFCURSOR)

  v_query varchar2(900);

  is

  BEGIN

  if(age > 10)
    then
        v_query:= 'select * from (select s.name,s.location from Student s where s.age = age)';
        open sresult for(v_query);
     else
          v_query:= 'select * from (select s.name,s.age from Student s where s.mobile = mobile)';
         open sresult for(v_query);
      
 endif;

  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in a declaration of procedure. Your declaration should look like this.

```
create or replace procedure select_proc_student(

  name varchar2(20), age number,
  mobile number,
  sresult out SYS_REFCURSOR) is

  v_query varchar2(900);

  begin

  end;
```

Comment: Showing not all variables bound

Answer (score 0):

The `age` argument is out of scope within the dynamic SQL you are running. If you wanted to use that you would need a bind variable:

```
v_query:= 'select * from (select s.name,s.location from Student s where s.age = :age)';
open sresult for v_query using age;
```

The reference to `age` within the string is now `:age`, indicating a bind variable; the value is then supplied with `using age`.

You don't need dynamic SQL though, you can just do:

```
open sresult for
  select * from (select s.name,s.location from Student s where s.age = p_age);
```

Here I've changed the name of the argument `age` to `l_age`, otherwise it will use the column value, and that condition will always be true (unless the value is null).

And you don't need the subquery so simplify that to:

```
open sresult for
  select s.name,s.location from Student s where s.age = p_age;
```

And the same for the mobile branch, so that becomes:

```
create or replace procedure select_proc_student (
  p_name varchar2,
  p_age number,
  p_mobile number,
  sresult out SYS_REFCURSOR
) as
begin

  if (p_age > 10) then
    open sresult for
      select s.name, s.location
      from student s
      where s.age = p_age;
  else
    open sresult for
      select s.name, s.location
      from student s
      where s.mobile = p_mobile;
      
  end if;
end;
```

I've corrected structure a bit, but that was unrelated to the error you reported. I've left the `p_name` argument even though you aren't using it; if you remove it then you need to adjust anything calling this.

You could also combine the queries so you only open the cursor in one place:

```
...
begin
  open sresult for
    select s.name, s.location
    from student s
    where (p_age > 10 and s.age = p_age)
    or ((p_age is null or p_age <= 10) and s.mobile = p_mobile);
end;
```

Comment: I got ==> self-deadlock detected while trying to mutex pin cursor 0x7FFB63B7D5F0

Comment: Mmm, lovely... seems to be a known bug in 12.1, see [this](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2039379_1.html), though not sure how this code would trigger that.

Comment: I've just noticed the code still wasn't right; I've removed the `(20)` from the argument declaration as it isn't valid there, and spurious parentheses around the `open ... for`. Not sure if either of those could be responsible for the deadlock, it seems unlikely but I guess try with the amended code. If the error persists then you (or your DBA) probably need to talk to Oracle support.

Comment: @Shankar - does the updated code still cause a deadlock? And if so, when; as you compile the procedure, or when you call it?

Comment: Giving not all variables bound

Comment: There aren't any bind variables in the modified code. SO is that coming from how you call it?

Comment: even though i bound getting not all variables bound  plz help me

Comment: @Shankar - [all three options compile](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=815e0ee8d82a17e884b0f38087b5e730). So the problem must be in how you are calling it, which you haven't shown. Maybe ask a new question about the new problem?

Comment: {call select_proc_student(?,?,?)}

Comment: The procedure has four arguments, unless you removed the name one. Ask a new question showing the Java code where you are making that call, and how you are binding the values for the in and out arguments.